How to Change the ID of Username and Password Input Fields in Keycloak Login Page?
I am using Keycloak for authentication in my application, and I need to customize the login page. Specifically, I need to change the IDs of the username and password input fields. The reason for this is that I have multiple login screens on the same domain but different paths, and I need unique IDs for each.
It also relates to realms. Currently autofill does not separate admin users and regular users credentials.
I tried to look trough keycloak doc and also into themes. But i was unable to find the answer
